# How expensive is Timer.Change?

Tags: c#, performance, timer

Consider a server with a performance-sensitive, highly-parallel, C# processing pipeline where we want to raise an event if something *stops* happening, e.g. the flow of media.

One theorized approach is to create a timer that is delayed continuously by the pipeline. By way of a simplistic example:

```
const int IDLE_MILLIS = 1000; // 1 second

Timer timer = new Timer(IDLE_MILLIS, () =>
{
   Console.WriteLine("Pipeline is idle.");
});

void ProcessMediaFrame(MediaFrame frame)
{
    timer.Change(IDLE_MILLIS, Timeout.Infinite);

    // pipeline is not idle
}
```

How expensive is the `Change` method here? (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.timer.change)

Does the `Timer` consume any resources while idle?

Comment: You can do some research in [sources](https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#mscorlib/system/threading/timer.cs,9c6e2403064ef532) to see how it works

Comment: No, it doesn't consume any resources see the [source](https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#mscorlib/system/threading/timer.cs,7aa651a6c9decb8f) about it.

Comment: I don't see any constructors for the timer you linked to which match the code you've written. Are you sure you're looking at the documentation for the same timer? Or am I missing something?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The performance note in the [source code](https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#mscorlib/system/threading/timer.cs,32) (thanks Codexer for linking the correct file) says your case is exactly what they've optimized for.

> We assume that timers are created and destroyed frequently, but rarely actually fire.
>
> ...
>
> - timeouts for operations ... almost never fire, because the whole point is that the timer only fires if something has gone wrong.